# Laço for não sendo completado

Tags: c

Sou iniciante em programação e ainda estou cometendo diversos erros, vocês poderia me auxiliar a encontrar o porquê do laço for não está completando o laço?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int N, X[N], controle = 0;
    int i, menor = 0, posicao = 0;

    setbuf(stdin, NULL);

    scanf("%d", &N);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &controle); 

        X[i] = controle;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if(X[i] <= menor){
            menor = [i];
            posicao = i;
        }
    }

    printf("Menor valor: %d\n", menor);
    printf("Posicao: %d\n", posicao);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Da maneira como declarou o array X não tem valor de N conhecido no momento da declaração. Declare o array após ler a variável N.
Se você partir considerando menor como sendo o primeiro elemento do array é mais abrangente do que considerar o menor como zero. Da maneira como fez se todos os elementos do array forem positivos ele não determinará o menor deles;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int N, controle = 0;
    int i, menor = 0, posicao = 0;

    setbuf(stdin, NULL);

    scanf("%d", &N);
    int X[N];
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &X[i]); 
    }

    menor = X[0];
    posicao = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++){
        if(X[i] < menor){
            menor = X[i];
            posicao = i;
        }
    }

    printf("Menor valor: %d\n", menor);
    printf("Posicao: %d\n", posicao);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ahhh, compreendi perfeitamente, muito obrigado!